# Access: Issue Creating SQL View Through VBA - Unions not allowed in subquery

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, view, union

First of all, let me preface this with something I almost always say in my few posts so far, which is that I'm not an IT/tech person. I'm an accountant who likes to dabble a little bit in SQL and so forth but with very minimal knowledge of VBA, so I apologize in advance if this is a super-easy question or it's already been covered. But I was not able to find anything directly related to this specific error.

Trying to use MS Access to create a view from SQL that includes a Union and getting the following error: Run-time error '-2147217900 (800040e14)': Unions not allowed in a subquery. Code is as follows:

```
   Sub Create_View()
    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Set conn = CurrentProject.Connection
    conn.Execute "CREATE VIEW Test_VW AS SELECT A.Unit as Unit, A.Spend as Spend, A.Date as Date, A.Type as Type FROM Table1 A UNION ALL SELECT B.Unit as Unit, B.Spend as Spend, B.Date as Date, B.Type as Type FROM Table2 B;"
            Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow 
End Sub
```

This is the code as it is right now, but I've also tried UNION instead of UNION ALL, SELECT * FROM both tables as opposed to the individual columns (both tables are only the 4 listed columns, which are also the same data type), and with the columns and tables unaliased.

Something I should point out that maybe could be the issue, but I wouldn't think it is is that the "Tables" in the code are actually views that I created in Access without VBA (as in just regular SQL). These now appear as "Queries" in the database. However, I did write the VBA with the initial SQL that's defining the views, and I returned the same error. So I don't think that's the issue.

EDIT: Also, I should point out that to test, I was able to create a view from the same VBA for the top level query without the UNION.

At any rate, I'm not sure where the subquery is in the SQL, so maybe it's a syntax error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Rather explicit error message. I tested and definitely does not work with a UNION.

Comment: The subquery is the SELECT statement.

Comment: Thank you @June7. I guess I don't think of subqueries in terms of unions, i.e. these are two separate outer queries (non-subqueries) that are built on top of each other, but maybe that's the wrong way to look at it from a technical standpoint. 

Regardless, it sounds like based on your testing that this specific VBA won't work with UNION. Do you think there is some VBA that exists or could be created to execute this task? I would think what I'm trying to do isn't super-complex, so there should be some solution out there.

Thanks again!

Comment: Maybe using QueryDefs would work with UNION. Why do you need to programmatically build query objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QueryDefs can handle UNION. Alias field and table names are not needed.

```
Sub test()
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("TestVW", "SELECT Unit, Spend, Date, Type FROM Table1 " & _
                                    "UNION ALL SELECT Unit, Spend, Date, Type FROM Table2;"
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
End Sub
```

Strongly advise not to use reserved words like Date as names.

Comment: Definitely works, and I did not use Date as the name in the actual query. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

That error message, *"Unions not allowed in a subquery"*, is not very helpful in your situation.

Access supports 2 DDL operations related to queries: `CREATE VIEW`; and `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

`CREATE VIEW` can be used for only simple `SELECT` queries.  `CREATE PROCEDURE` must be used for more complicated `SELECT` queries (such as `UNION`) and for "action" queries.

So you could avoid your current error by using `CREATE PROCEDURE` instead of `CREATE VIEW`.  However you would then encounter a different error, *"The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect"*, due to unbracketed reserved words used as column aliases.  You can drop the unneeded column aliases to avoid that error.

Here's an adaptation of your code which worked for me in Access 2010.

```vb
Dim strSql As String

strSql = "CREATE PROCEDURE Test_VW AS" & vbCrLf & _
    "SELECT A.Unit, A.Spend, A.Date, A.Type FROM Table1 A" & vbCrLf & _
    "UNION ALL SELECT B.Unit, B.Spend, B.Date, B.Type FROM Table2 B;"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql
```